What's the meaning of " another got steel"?

said Earl. “I don’t claim to be nothing more than I am. You maybe can
fight, I’m an upholsterer.” “That’s the way it goes.” “One man got
muscles, another got steel. It all come out the same.” They drank in
silence. When the woman returned, Tully rose and went out.

It is an excerpt from the novel Fat City by Leonard Gardner.
Does the word "steel" here mean?:

Some people work with their muscle, others with their tools.
Some have power, others have courage.

Tully is a boxer and he is in a bar and talking with the Earl's girlfriend (her name Oma), and after she got down her stool and went to the lavatory, Earl put a glass of port on the bar in front of Tully, and talked with other as mentioned above.
I think Earl indirectly threatens Tully. when Oma returned, Tully immediately went out. So i think the word "steel" here maybe means "courage".

It's a metaphoric usage from a very non-standard speaker, so don;t read too much into it. But steel here means grit, courage (probably reduced from nerves of steel). Sometimes the "weaker" boxer might win the fight simply because he has the determination not to concede defeat. And that meaning will be in lots of online dictionaries, I'm sure. Your "work with tools" suggestion is "interesting", but it's not right for the general case. But the speaker might be misusing the term, for all I know.

A weapon?  A knife or a gun?

@TimR Or a sword, in certain time periods.  I don't know about steel for a gun (if anything you might use lead rather than steel as a metonym for the bullets), but a knife also works.

Yes, steel takes the first sense 3 for steel
in M+W

a quality (such as hardness of mind or spirit) that suggests steel


nerves of steel


Yes, the person who has steel may not need to resort to their fists, but be able to psych an adversary.

Thanks, @Weather Vane.   Yes, the same adjectives like strong and hard associated with the metal apply to such non-physical strength and toughness.
